# closing a div while click anywhere outside that div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a jquery navigation bar. So when I click on `div` main, a new `div` will slide down and I want to add an option to close the window if we click anywhere outside the newly opened window. This is the code that I have used but it is not working.

The newly opened `div` doesn't close when I click anywhere outside it.

```
var $s = $("#main");    
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  $(document.body).click(function()
  {
   $('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
   if (!$s.has(this).length) 
   {
      $s.hide();
   }    
 });
});
```

Comment: Can you describe **what** is not working?

Comment: the newly opened div wudnt close when I click anywhere outside it..

Comment: Please use better grammar and spelling when asking a question.

Comment: ok..Iam sorry abt that... Will explain in it in detail.. Iam trying to create a jquery nave bar.. The way I want it to wrk is like this.. There is a button .. when I click on it, a new division will slidedown with a whole list of items. So if I click on the button again, that div will close. Bt I want to add one more option to this, ie if I click anywhere outside the div also, it shuld close..

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
if(!$(event.target).is('#main')) {
   // your code to close the div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by attaching an event to the "body" of the page is the simplest approach.

```
    $("body").click(function () {
        ....
    });
```

You are trying to use a javascript dom reference, where you need to use a jquery selector to apply jquery events.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question asked at least once a week. I usually get away with this but it depends on your logic and markup.

```
$menu.focusout(function(){ 
    $(this).slideUp(); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $_theDiv = $('#the_div')

$_theDiv.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
} );
// stops the event from bubbling up to the body.

$(document).click(function(){ $_theDiv.hide(); });
//Now any time a click event bubbles to the top of the document, you know it wasn't #theDiv
```

I'm going to go with a basic example to get to the general idea. We show #theDiv. Now we want it to disappear if we click anywhere but on #theDiv. So we use stopPropagation on the event object. Normally when you click, the click also goes up the parent, and the parent of that parent, and keeps going until you hit the document. This is called "event bubbling." Since we stopped the bubbling, we know if a click reaches the document (the HTML tag), that it couldn't have come from #theDiv because e.stopPropagation, prevented it. Bubbling is very useful, so only use stopPropagation on elements that have no children (aren't containers). Things like links and images and buttons.